# Added button and app crushed

Tags: android

I tried to made button that goes to webpages but when I lunch app it crushes. There are no errors tos. What to do? Mby there is a problem in XML?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }


       addButtonClickListener(); //Soc network buttons

    }

    public void addButtonClickListener() //soc network buttons
    {
        Button facebook = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Facebookpoga); //Facebook pogai
        facebook.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View arg)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



    }
```

Comment: No errors in `LogCat`?

Comment: Post your logcat, is the button inside your fragment?

Comment: The problem most probably is that you dont have a button with id `Facebookpoga` in layout `activity_main`..

Comment: "crashed" word does not provide info for us, when your app crashed and you are going to ask question in SO, you should include some parts of `LogCat` as well as a related snippet code, So please include your logcat to the post

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered a similar problem, lot of times while learning the basics of Android development. And I can tell that the problem is that, for some reasons `findViewById(id)` returns null. This started happening after an update when eclipse started including a `Fragment layout` with the `main layout` for each `Activity`.
I sorted out the problems by putting all such calls in `onStart()` instead of `onCreate()`. And I am sure that sorts out the problem for you to. 
Do this:

```
protected void onStart(){
   addButtonClickListener(); //Soc network buttons
}
```

Add this function after `onCreate()`, hope it helps. And yes, remove the listener call `addButtonClickListener();` from `onCreate().`

I guess the problem may be because `Fragment layout` is not instantinated immediately after `setContentView()` which results in `findViewById(R.id.Facebookpoga);` to return *null*, because no such `View` with id `R.id.Facebookpoga` is created yet.